# Python - matrix multiplication code problem

Tags: python, matrix-multiplication

I have this exercise where I get to build a simple neural network with one input layer and one hidden layer... I made the code below to perform a simple matrix multiplication, but it's not doing it properly as when I do the multiplication by hand. What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
          #toes %win  #fans
ih_wgt = ([0.1, 0.2, -0.1],  #hid[0]
           [-0.1, 0.1, 0.9],  #hid[1]
           [0.1, 0.4, 0.1])  #hid[2]

          #hid[0] hid[1] #hid[2]
ho_wgt = ([0.3, 1.1, -0.3], #hurt?
           [0.1, 0.2, 0.0],  #win?
           [0.0, 1.3, 0.1])  #sad?

weights = [ih_wgt, ho_wgt]

def w_sum(a,b):
    assert(len(a) == len(b))
    output = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        output += (a[i] * b[i])
    return output

def vect_mat_mul(vec, mat): 
  assert(len(vec) == len(mat)) 
  output = [0, 0, 0]
  for i in range(len(vec)): 
    output[i]= w_sum(vec, mat[i])
    return output

def neural_network(input, weights):
  hid = vect_mat_mul(input, weights[0])
  pred = vect_mat_mul(hid, weights[1])
  return pred


toes = [8.5, 9.5, 9.9, 9.0]
wlrec = [0.65, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9]
nfans = [1.2, 1.3, 0.5, 1.0]

input = [toes[0],wlrec[0],nfans[0]]

pred = neural_network(input, weights)
print(pred)
```

the output of my code is:

> [0.258, 0, 0]

The way I attempted to solve it by hand is as follows:
I multiplied the input vector [8.5, 0.65, 1.2] with the input weight matrix

```
ih_wgt = ([0.1, 0.2, -0.1],  #hid[0]
           [-0.1, 0.1, 0.9],  #hid[1]
           [0.1, 0.4, 0.1])  #hid[2]
```

> [0.86, 0.295, 1.23]

the output vector is then fed into the network as an input vector which is then multiplied by the hidden weight matrix

```
ho_wgt = ([0.3, 1.1, -0.3], #hurt?
           [0.1, 0.2, 0.0],  #win?
           [0.0, 1.3, 0.1])  #sad?
```

the correct output prediction:

> [0.2135, 0.145, 0.5065]

Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! Only a simple indentation thing is the reason:

```
def vect_mat_mul(vec, mat): 
  assert(len(vec) == len(mat)) 
  output = [0, 0, 0]
  for i in range(len(vec)): 
    output[i]= w_sum(vec, mat[i])
  return output                      # <-- This one was inside the for loop
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! I fixed the indentation, now the output is different but still wrong.
>[0.555, 0.9800000000000001, 0.9650000000000001]

Comment: @user6688, It gives `[0.21350000000000002, 0.14500000000000002, 0.5065]` when I correct that indentation and run on my machine. Can you check if you are using the same values you used in the question above?